# sql/stored procedure to find matching records in word tags table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have e.g. two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE doc
  (  doc_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,  doc_text VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL
  );

CREATE TABLE doc_tag
  (  doc_id INT NOT NULL
  ,  tag_word VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,  PRIMARY KEY(doc_id, tag_word)
  ,  KEY ix_doc_tag_word_doc_id (tag_word, doc_id)
  );
```

A record in the table doc may have e.g. 5, 10 or even 20 related word tags in the `doc_tag` table.

How would I write a stored procedure in `MYSQL` to which I can supply a `doc_id` for a BASE `doc` record and minimum number of matching tag words (table `doc_tag`). The result should be the `doc_id`s for OTHER `doc` records that have the specified minimum number of words (as stored in `doc_tag`) in common with the BASE `doc` record.

So my original BASE `doc` record may have 10 tag words in the `doc_tag` table, but I want to find all OTHER `doc` records that share at least 5 of the 10 tag words in `doc_tag`. It does not matter which of the 10 that matches as long as at least 5 of the `doc_tag` words belonging to the BASE `doc` record are also to be found in the `doc_tag` records belonging to the OTHER `doc` records.

An example:
BASE:
`doc.doc_id`: 1
`doc_text`: "This is my BASE document"

`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: book
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: table
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: chair
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: wall
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: floor
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: house
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: phone
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 1, `doc_tag.tag_word`: ceiling

A matching OTHER `doc` record:
`doc.doc_id`: 20187
`doc_text`: "This is one tag matching OTHER document"

`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: ceiling
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: floor
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: room
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: house
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: wall
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: phone
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: basement
`doc_tag.doc_id`: 20187, `doc_tag.tag_word`: corridor

The reason that record is matching is that the words "ceiling", "floor", "house", "phone" and "wall" are tag words for both `doc`records. It does not matter that both have other tag words that are not shared.

Possibly, preparation code to identify the possible combinations of 5 of the original 10 tag words is needed to create the final queries. However, I have the feeling that there is beautiful and compact way to do this, which just eludes me.

If the stored procedure language of mySQL is not equipped to handle this, feel free to suggest a solution in another dialect, e.g. MSSQL's T-SQL. It is mainly the algorithm that one would use that I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT OTHER.doc_id
FROM doc_tag BASE
INNER JOIN doc_tag OTHER ON BASE.doc_id <> OTHER.doc_id AND 
                            BASE.tag_word = OTHER.tag_word
WHERE BASE.doc_id = @baseid 
GROUP BY OTHER.doc_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= @min_records
```

Basically, you are taking all of the tags for the base document, filtering for all other instances of those tags, then grouping those tags by document id to get a count.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help!  
Would have increased the rating on the answer, but as a new user I apparently have to earn more reputation before I am allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `group by` and `having` clause:

```
select doc_id
from doc d join
     doc_tag t
     on d.doc_id = t.doc_id
group by doc_id
having count(*) >= 5;
```

Comment: This will only find documents that have a minimum of any 5 tag words associated with them. However, I am trying to find matching doc records to an original base doc record, and the matching criteria is that the BASE and OTHER documents must share at least 5 tag words (those stored in the doc_dag table). I will try to make my original question a bit more clear.